# Black screen after FileVault restart

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, filevault

I’ve recently bought a 2014 MacBook Air 11 and while I was going through the encryption shutdown and hasn’t restarted. Just sat there with a black screen and the Apple logo glowing. I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix this or what the problem is?

Comment: Is its power supply connected?

Comment: Does your problem looks like this one: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/216294/22003 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a current time machine backup, you could try restarting your MacBook in recovery mode. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314   Just a thought as I'm sure there are more experienced users who can help you. Good luck!